# gnubg lib not load in backgammon

Tags: android

I forked this game (it.alcacoop.backgammon) that exists on github.

I downloaded it and imported it to android studio 1.5.1 and it raised an error during compile time which I solved with the following change.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:7.5+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:7.5+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
```

in buld.gradle in root folder
(change plus with zero )

now I can compile game and run it but in run time on logo it force close with this error

```
02-28 06:15:09.205 2271-2287/it.alcacoop.backgammon E/EGL_genymotion: [getAttribValue] Bad attribute idx
02-28 06:15:09.205 2271-2287/it.alcacoop.backgammon E/EGL_genymotion: tid 2287: eglGetConfigAttrib(573): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
02-28 06:15:09.205 2271-2287/it.alcacoop.backgammon E/EGL_genymotion: [getAttribValue] Bad attribute idx
02-28 06:15:09.205 2271-2287/it.alcacoop.backgammon E/EGL_genymotion: tid 2287: eglGetConfigAttrib(573): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
02-28 06:15:11.089 2271-2287/it.alcacoop.backgammon E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 186

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gnubg from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/it.alcacoop.backgammon-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/it.alcacoop.backgammon-1, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:355)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:
at it.alcacoop.backgammon.MainActivity.initEngine(MainActivity.java:508)
at it.alcacoop.backgammon.layers.SplashScreen$2.run(SplashScreen.java:116)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.RunnableAction.run(RunnableAction.java:42)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.RunnableAction.act(RunnableAction.java:32)
at it.alcacoop.backgammon.actions.MySequenceAction.act(MySequenceAction.java:27)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.act(Actor.java:95)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.act(Group.java:50)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.act(Stage.java:223)
at it.alcacoop.backgammon.layers.SplashScreen.render(SplashScreen.java:88)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:422)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
02-28 06:15:15.913 2271-2271/it.alcacoop.backgammon E/AndroidGraphics: waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing
```

That say library gnubg not found but it is in lib folder in Desktop folder
thanks for your attention.

Comment: Desktop != Android. You'll need to build another project. Did you read: https://github.com/alcacoop/it.alcacoop.backgammon/blob/master/android/libs/README

Comment: thanks i solve it by your comment

Comment: Format and remove unneccessary text